# Rails 3 assets & CSS relative URLS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline

I have several CSS files which make referece to images using relative paths like `url( "../img/my_image.jpg" )`.

Everything works in `development` but in `production` environment, as all the CSS files are packed in one file and the structure is lost, also the relatives paths are lost, and the images are not found.

#### Details of my structure

I have an *assets* structure like this:

```
/app
  /assets
    /plugins
      /my_plugin
        /img
          my_image.jpg
        /css
          my_css.css
```

*(`/my_plugin` can be any plugin that is a groups of `css`, `js` and `images` files like Twitter Bootstrap any any other)*

Into the `/app/assets/plugins/my_plugin/my_css.css` I have something like:

```
background-image: url("../img/my_image.jpg");
```

In the `/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css`:

```
*= require css/my_css.css
```

And finally in the `head` of my `html` file:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
```

What should I do to fix the issue?

#### Update

[Mini application to reproduce the issue](https://github.com/fguillen/RailsAssetsTest), in the [README](https://github.com/fguillen/RailsAssetsTest/blob/master/README.md) there are instruction to install and reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't see a problem with concatenating CSS files. And you don't have to include your deeply nested CSS files manually: by default, application.css already does this in the line `*= require_tree .`

And images will repeat your `app/assets/images` structure. To deal with them correctly both in  development and production environments you have [the respective Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets). Check its section *2.2 Coding Links to Assets*. There's explanation about coding paths to your image files:

CSS via ERb:

```
 url(<%= asset_path 'image.png' %>)
```

CSS via Sass:

```
 image-url("rails.png")
```

All these weird hex characters at the end of your precompiled images will be respected automatically.

**UPD**

I see you don't need the assets pipeline feature for your plugins at all. Your styles/scripts are already minified. You can move your `plugins` folder into your `public` folder (to become `<APP_ROOT>/public/plugins/`).

Then **delete** the following line from your `application.css`:

```
*= require bootstrap/css/bootstrap
```

Instead **add** the following lines to your template `application.html.erb`:

```
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" %>
```

Now you have to be able to switch between your themes easily by replacing your `public/plugins/bootstrap`'s content.

**UPD 2**

Probably you have to explicitly tell *Rails* to `precompile` your *plugin assets*:

```
# /config/environments/production.rb
config.assets.precompile += %w( bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css )
```

Comment: The problem of the CSS packaging is that it removes the CSS route path so the _relative paths_ from the CSS to the image is not correct any more. I'm not using CSS in _ERb_ format neither in _Sass_ my CSS and images come from a plugin with its own structure of `js`, `css` and `img` folders that I want to respect for maintenance concerns.

Comment: @fguillen You don't have to make any dramatic changes. Just rename your `*.css` files to, say, `*.css.scss` and specify `url()`s as: `image-url('img/my_image.jpg')` (NOTE: no `..` at the beginning). And I don't know why you wrote: `config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "my_plugin")` -- this path is already inside the `assets` folder.

Comment: I know is not very dramatic, but, among other things, I'm playing with different themes of same plugin (let's call it `bootstrap`) and I prefer to just copy paste and refresh. There are also other relative routes like **@imports**, **@fontfaces**,... I'm looking for a non-intrusive solution, maybe creating different packages by plugin, I don't know. About the `config.assets.paths` I'm gonna remove it from my question to avoid noise, you're right I don't need it.

Comment: I have added in the question an application that reproduces the issue, let me know if this is better explanation of my issue.

Comment: @fguillen See the UPD section in my answer.

Comment: Exactly this is what I found out, look my own answer, I'll accept yours. Let me update your answer with the `config.assets.precompile` instructions.

Answer (score 2):

I have been able to solve the issue moving my *plugin assets* to the `/app/vendor/assets/plugins` where I think is better place due they are not assets directly related to my application but infact *vendor* assets.

Then we have:

```
/app
  /vendor
    /assets
      /plugins
        /my_plugin
          /img
            my_image.jpg
          /css
            my_css.css
```

And we load the main `css` in another `stylesheet_link_tag` call like this:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "my_plugin/css/my_css", :media => "all" %>
```

At this moment everything looks right but *Rails* complains about `my_css.css` is not compiled even if we run `rake assets:precompile`.

The solution is to tell *Rails* explicitly to compile this file:

```
# /config/environments/production.rb
config.assets.precompile += %w( my_plugin/css/my_css.css )
```

Now the `rake assets:precompile` will compile our plugin css and the `production` environment works properly even with *relative urls*.

Check the [diff changes those have resolved the issue](https://github.com/fguillen/RailsAssetsTest/commit/7330bf9a6ab71d6c7c39f40fecd39fbd5c204f6c)

Comment: Glad you've solved the issue. Just keep in mind that you got here half-pipelined plugin: your CSS file does have a digest, but urls inside it - don't (you can't easily invalidate cached icons this way). But I hope it won't be a problem!